# Table overflowing the column width in a 2 column document (svjour3)

Tags: tables, two-column, overflow

I am trying to write the following simple table within one column under springer svjour3 format. It is not only overflowing the column but also producing lots of bad boxes. I have tried with l/c/r/manual width specification under tabular and tabularx respectively without success.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Accuracy comparison %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Accuracy comparison with similar approaches}
\label{tab:accuracy comparison}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}
                            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                            X
                             }
\toprule
\thead{Reference} &\thead{ Learning\\approach} & \thead{Initial\\movement}& \thead{Accuracy\\claimed(\%)}\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{[1]} & KNN(K=1) & Walking/running & 93\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{[2]} & Threshold & Walking & 72\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{[3]} & Threshold & Walking & 87.5\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Implemented system} & Threshold & Walking & 94.45\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Please help.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering.

Comment: As Ivan said you should provide a complete MWE but you are bound to get bad boxes with that code since you are using `tabularx` without `X` columns.

Comment: @Bukaida -- I do not have the document class `svjour3` -- using `multicol` -- please see the answer below

Comment: Modified the OP into MWE. Adding 'X' column did not have any effect on appearance apparently

Comment: In fact replacing 'c' with 'X' for the last column, made the header alignment unbalanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

**Edid:**
with changed reference data:

[image]

- reduced is font size in column headers
- for last column is used `S` column type defined in the `\siunitx` package
- remove `\tabcolsep`  at front and the end of table
- enable multi lines cells' contents

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Accuracy comparison %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[ht]
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Accuracy comparison with similar approaches}
\label{tab:accuracy comparison}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}X X X S[table-format=2.2] @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Reference} 
                &\thead{ Learning\\approach} 
                    & \thead{Initial\\movement}
                        & {\thead{Accuracy\\claimed (\%)}}   \\
    \midrule
{[1]}       & KNN(K=1) & Walking/ running & 93\\
{[2]}       & Threshold & Walking & 72\\
{[3]}       & Threshold & Walking & 87.5\\
Our system  & Threshold & Walking & 94.45\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

**Note:** if you not like to use `siunitx` package and SI units systems, than simple delete this package in preamble in replace `S[table-format=2.2]` in table headers with desired column type (for example `c`, etc.). This mater of personal preferences, i.e. it is opinion based. In any case, tabel not spill out of column, as you asked in question.

Comment: 90% as per expectation, however, is it possible to avoid \usepackage{siunitx} and still get a similar result? Also the word "Implemented"  in the last record may be substituted by "Our", if it gives better look.

Comment: @Bukaida, you can make these changes yourself :-). If you not like `S` column type, you use anyone else (for example `c`), however, to my opinion `S` gives the nicer alignment of numbers.

Answer (score 4):

I would simplify and streamline the look of the table by using much less **bold-facing**. AFter all, the table is quite small -- there's no chance the readers will become confused over what's the header material and what's the "body" of the table.

The `svjour3` document class has some particular idea about captions are supposed to look like, and these ideas are not compatible with those of the `caption` and `subcaption` packages. Hence, I wouldn't load these two packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newlength\mylenA \settowidth\mylenA{Implemented}
\newlength\mylenB \settowidth\mylenB{KNN ($K=1$)}
\newlength\mylenC \settowidth\mylenC{movement}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Accuracy comparison with similar approaches}
\label{tab:accuracy comparison} 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} P{\mylenA} P{\mylenB} P{\mylenC} C @{}}
\toprule
Reference &
Learning approach & 
Initial movement  & 
Accuracy claimed~(\%) \\
\midrule
{[1]} & KNN ($K=1$) & Walking\slash running & 93\phantom{.00}\\
{[2]} & Threshold & Walking & 72\phantom{.00}\\
{[3]} & Threshold & Walking & 87.5\phantom{0}\\
Implemented system & Threshold & Walking & 94.45 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx, array, tabularx, booktabs, makecell}
\title{Table formatting}
\author{The geniuses at SE}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \doublespacing
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        
        \section{Introduction}      
        \lipsum[1-1]
        \noindent
        \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
                \begin{tabular}
                    {p{0.5in}p{0.75in}p{0.75in}p{0.75in}}
                    \toprule
                    \thead{Reference} &\thead{ Learning\\approach} & \thead{Initial\\movement}& \thead{Accuracy\\claimed(\%)}\\
                    \midrule\\
                    \textbf{[1]} & KNN(K=1) & \makecell[l]{Walking/\\running} & 93\\
                    \addlinespace
                    \textbf{[2]} & Threshold & Walking & 72\\
                    \addlinespace
                    \textbf{[3]} & Threshold & Walking & 87.5\\
                    \addlinespace
                    \textbf{\makecell[l]{Implemented \\system}} & \makecell[l]{\\Threshold} & \makecell[l]{\\Walking} & \makecell[l]{\\94.45}\\
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
        
        \addvspace{\intextsep}
        
        \lipsum[1-2]
        
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```